# Django: instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This is my model

```
class Business(models.Model):
    business_type = models.ManyToManyField(BusinessType)
    establishment_type = models.ForeignKey(EstablishmentType)
    website = models.URLField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

in my view I'm trying to save a record as follows:

```
business = BusinessForm(request.POST or None)
if business.is_valid():
            busi = business.save(commit=False)
            bt = BusinessType.objects.get(id=6)
            busi.business_type = bt
            et = EstablishmentType.objects.get(id=6)
            busi.establishment_type = et
            busi.save()
```

However, it gives me an error

```
'Business' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

How do i save this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to save the instance of the model before adding any m2m fields. Remember you have to add the m2m field with the `.add()` method, not assign it directly to the field as you are doing.

```
if business.is_valid():
    busi = business.save(commit=False)
    et = EstablishmentType.objects.get(id=6)
    busi.establishment_type = et
    busi.save()
    bt = BusinessType.objects.get(id=6)
    busi.business_type.add(bt)
```

Note that the `save_m2m` method is available on the `modelform` object when you do `form_obj.save(commit=False)`. If the model form was given m2m data, you should use the save_m2m method. If you want to assign it manually like you're doing, you need to add it separately like my code above.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is out there still looking for answer to this, I was having the same issue and could not find a solution anywhere.

Here is where I had gone wrong:
In my model, I was overriding the save() method in order to not persist data to my database.  It seems obvious in retrospect, but overriding the save() method was causing the issue because my primary key was never actually being generated.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Save `busi` before attempting to assign to `busi.business_type`.

Comment: `if business.is_valid():
            busi = business.save()`  still gives me the same error in the traceback it shows `busi = business.save()`

Answer (score 0):

try it with this order:

```
if business.is_valid():
            busi = business.save(commit=False)
            et = EstablishmentType.objects.get(id=6)
            busi.establishment_type = et
            busi.save() #with commit == true
            bt = BusinessType.objects.get(id=6)
            busi.business_type = bt
            busi.save() #here you save many to many
```

Comment: i get an error `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'` on line `busi.save(commit=False)`

Comment: yes, sorry, I remove it, commit argument just used in the ModelForm instances, not in Model instances.

Comment: This is all wrong @Dantario. You can't assign to `business_type`. You must `busi.business_type.add(bt)` as it is like a collection. There is also no commit kwarg on a model instance.