# django model clean issue

Tags: django, validation, model, many-to-many

Im working in two models ralated via many to many, here's the relevant code:

```
class Curso(models.Model):
    horarios = models.ManyToManyField(Horario, related_name = 'cursos')
    ...
    def clean(self):
       ...
       self.horarios.all()
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        ...
```

`Horarios` has been already defined, now when i try to create an of curso in the admin interface i get an error pointing to `self.horarios.all()`:

```
'Curso' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

And it makes sense as it has not been saved, so my problem is, how do i access the value of `horarios` in the current `Curso` instance that is being saved?.

thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't the Horario model have its own clean method? Why would you need to work with it in the Curso clean method?

Comment: @jdi horario = schedule, i need horario not to be present on some Curso instance at the same time, that's how i validate them, iteraring over them.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090859/django-instance-needs-to-have-a-primary-key-value-before-a-many-to-many-relatio

Answer (score 2):

The error seems pretty straight forward to me -- you simply cannot call a `ManyToMany` before an object is saved.

You can reproduce the error: `Curso().horarios`

Clearly you can't be doing validation on relationships that can't possibly exist, so simply wrap your call in a `if self.pk`

```
if self.pk:
   self.horarios.all()
```